# jquery validation in model popup form does not work correctly

Tags: jquery, validation

all I used the jQuery validation in my modal popup form. But when the validation is true, need to click the submit button next time to submit the form. I would like to know how to submit the form when I click the submit popup button and validation is true. Also I want to close the dialog when the cancel button is click. Thanks all.

```
    $('.adddomain').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#adddomainform").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            show: '',
            resizable: false,
            position: 'center',
            stack: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            title: "",
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Save",
                    click: function () {
                        if ($("#adddomainform").valid()) {  //Check for Valid
                            $('#adddomainform').submit();
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Invalid");
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
   });

   $("#adddomainform").validate({            
        rules: {
            domainname: {
                required: true,
                validdomain: true,
                duplicate: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            domainname: {
                required: 'Please enter domain name.'                
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please, update your question following the MCVE guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve